# regular expression to avoid repeat for 4 times

Tags: javascript, regex

I just tried a regular expression to avoid repeat of digits for more than 4 continuous times like `11111` and it is working fine:

`([0-9])\1{4}`

But I need to avoid repeat of digits for more than 6 times like `11111121` but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: "I want" is not a question. What have you tried, how did that fail?

Comment: @Clive I just edited my question. thanks for your good note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*(\d)(?:.*\1){6})(?!.*(\d)\2{4})\d+
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/7)